# How to mount Kubernetes directory as some other directory?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, nfs

I have a Kubernetes app that I want to copy to another environment.
The original app uses container directory */data/X* and synchronizes it with NFS server.

I have a following problems:

- I want to run new app in another environment and must not overwrite NFS storage of the original app
- I need to create */data/X* directory in the container of new app, as the developers rely on this directory inside container - they install software there and create files inside

My question is: Is there any option for me to create directory */data/Y* inside container on the environment and let it act as a folder */data/X* so the software is installed inside container correctly, files are created and NFS storage of the original app is not overwritten?

Comment: Hello, could you post the `YAML` manifest of your `Deployment` for more refence? If I understand your question correctly, I do think that an answer provided by @danielorn is the correct one. Could you edit your question with more details if that is not the case? Does the `NFS` server has a role in your new app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want the `/data/X` folder to be inside the running container and not on the NFS for this new environment?

If so you can make sure that `/data/X` folder is created as part of the image, for example by putting this line in the `Dockerfile`

```
RUN mkdir -p /data/X
```

In the original environment you mount NFS storage on `/data/X`. This will behave like mounts do in Linux, i.e that they shadow everything in `/data/X` on the local file system and you appear to read/write to the NFS share.

In the new environment you are creating you just skip mounting anything there. The developers can still use `/data/X` as they usually would, but the content will not be persisted and it will not be possible to share it between containers